# Using if statement with setters or not

Tags: java, coding-style

Imagine the following case:

```
int foo, bar;

... here the value of bar might change

if (foo != bar) {
    setFoo(bar);
}

setFoo(Object bar){
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

So here we have to integer values, and the value of a bar variable might change. Then we check with **if** statement if the bar has changed, and if It did, we change the value of a **foo** variable to **bars** value. Would here be better to just call the **setFoo** method everytime and leave out the **if** statement, or leave It as is, because this solution expresses "this value might not change". This is a rather subjective question, so I would like to see your view and Its explanation of the situation.

My personal opinion is, leave **if** statement.

Comment: As stated, the choice is totally subjective (and IMO not very interesting).  In other contexts, there may be objective reasons to avoid calling a setter when there is no change ... or in making the setter do the check itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `setFoo` everytime the stack is busier, thus is better to leave the function inside the **if** statement. A simple check like equals is less expensive and does not take up memory on the stack each time.